# What is the action of "breaking up clumps of rice" called?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

> > [image: The rice cooked in a pressure cooker for 20mins with proportional water.]
> >     [image: just broke the rice into finer pieces.]

I'm really not expressing the verb well. What's the correct way to instruct

You have to "break" the rice before eating?

Comment: Can you explain more the situation? I don't think there's a special word in English just for breaking up clumped-up rice.

Comment: "separate sticky rice"... still each to his own.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That’s called ***fluffing*** the rice.

Here’s [Bon Appetite](https://www.bonappetit.com/test-kitchen/cooking-tips/article/how-to-make-white-rice-effed-it-up) with their rice making instructions.
Note at the end where it says:

> Cover the pan tightly with lid. Let rice stand, covered, for 15-20 minutes to firm up. Remove the lid and fluff cooked rice with a fork.

Comment: Sweet. Thanks. In my language it is a verb which is a homonym with a slang. The slang in English is just the f-word. Word of the day. Any synonyms?

Comment: Certainly even *fluffing* has another meaning in English, but this is what it's called when you separate rice grains.

Comment: @technazi 'slang', like 'water', 'code' or 'software', is a mass noun. "...a homonym with slang". No 'a'.

Comment: Yes, this sounds right. You can 'break up the rice' or any clumped up thing, it is in chunks, like in the picture. 'fluff' has other meanings: the primary one to me is the noun down or feathers or light airy things, which by verbing the noun, you're making the rice become (light and airy that is).

Comment: @Mitch wow such details. Thanks for the correction and explanation. Also do you know the word for someone who is (I think belting) someone else's food by some type of contact. I have a significant pulp fiction dialog where she says I don't have crooties.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'belting' (but that's the problem, right? You don't know what the right word to use is?). Is this person stealing your food? Touching it? Spitting in it? Ruining it? You need to add more description with words you _do_ know. Also, there's no such thing as 'crooties'. I think you meant 'cooties' which is sort of a word only kids use for some vague unknown sickness/gross thing that other people can catch from you (like a sickness).

Comment: Right. That's the word I'm finding. Just touching it or tasting it with a spoon but putting the spoon back in the bowl. Yes cooties got it. That's right it's not significant in this case.

Comment: Oh, you might mean “Double dipping” where you use a utensil,  that’s been in your mouth, in a community serving dish.  Or when you dip a piece of food in a community condiment bowl, take a bite, and then dip that food again.

Comment: Really this should be a separate question though.

Comment: @Jim But what about water? When you have put your mouth on the bottles rim?

Comment: I wouldn’t classify that as “double dipping”. That’s just sharing a bottle.  But to be sure, the transfer of cooties problem  remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

It is possibly

> [decompaction](http://www.yourdictionary.com/decompaction)
>
> The act or process of making something less compact; often specifically the reversal of previous compaction

using *compact* defined as:

> to pack or press firmly together.